# Feature branching for mobile development

Tags: ios, heroku, mobile, github, feature-branch

I use feature branching for my web projects, where, for each feature, I create a new branch and open a pull request when the feature is ready to be tested by other members of the team.

Using [Heroku review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) and [Github collaborative code review](https://github.com/features) we can review the code and test the feature seamlessly (no pull, build, and so on..).

Now, we are developing a mobile app for ios/android using ionic2 and the testflight (ios) / beta (android) programs. The problem is that you can only have one build at a time, so features have to be tested one by one (i.e. PR1, B1, Merge PR1, open PR2, B2, Merge PR2 and so on). It considerably slows our development process.

So, do you known extra tooling/options/process for having many mobile builds on test at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/). You can have different builds there (one for each feature for example), and the tester is able to choose what version to install.